# ExtJS 6 TextArea readOnly : how to restrict mouse cursor inside textarea

Tags: extjs, cursor, textarea, mouse, readonly

I have a ExtJS6 textarea that has bind variable readOnly

```
bind:{
readOnly : '{someCondition}'
}
```

When the textarea has readOnly:true then on click of the text field mouse cursor is inside text area. I want to restrict mouse cursor when text area is readOnly.

Using "disabled" attribute works fine and does not allow mouse cursor inside text area,  but the vertical scrollbar with text area is not displayed. hence can not use this property.

Can you please suggest some solution.

Comment: for readOnly TextArea the mouse cursor should not be displayed inside textarea.

Comment: By readonly you mean you are not able to edit BUT cursor is seen in textfield ? If possible can you show some demo/image ?

Comment: When the field is readonly then i dont want the mouse cursor inside the textarea. I used this.blur() but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specified `editable` config

```
bind:{
  readOnly : '{someCondition}'
  editable : false({somecondition})
}
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22c0).

Comment: editable also did not work. the mouse cursor is still inside the text are. I  used this.blur() but that is not working.

Comment: it is working please refer fiddle. 
  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22c0

Comment: it does not display scrollbar if there is data. the code is  {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    maxLength: 100,
                    grow: true,
                    growMin:10,
                    growMax:90,
                  
,
                    bind: {
                        value: '(json data)',
                        readOnly:'{ some condition}'
                    },
                allowBlank: true
                }

Comment: I used below code, but this does not work : listeners: {focus: function(field)
                    {this.blur}}

Comment: because you have specify grow and growMax property, remove it and scrollbar will come .please refer same fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823009/1043031) provided by @Ronak Patel seems to work.  If you want to also prevent the user from using the mouse to select the text in the textarea, you can set `user-select` to `none`.  Although it's not a standard practice, you could also change the cursor to indicate to the user that they cannot select the text.
These changes can be made in the `writeableChange` event listener:

```
writeableChange: function () {
                        if (this.readOnly) {
                            this.inputEl.dom.style.userSelect = 'none';
                            this.inputEl.dom.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
                        } else {
                            this.inputEl.dom.style.userSelect = 'inherit';
                            this.inputEl.dom.style.cursor = 'inherit';
                        }
                    }
```

See updated fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22fc) (use the checkbox to make the textarea readOnly or not).